# Boost filesystem libraries don't work in debug mode

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm working on this little project which use boost:filesystem library. The problem is that boost:filesystem:path doesn't seem to work correctly in debug mode. Whenever I try to create a path object passing an std::string the constructor throws an exception (std::length_error) from this function

```
template <class U> inline
void dispatch(const std::string& c, U& to, const codecvt_type& cvt)
{
  if (c.size())
  convert(&*c.begin(), &*c.begin() + c.size(), to, cvt);
}
```

If i pass a wstring instead of a string at the costructor it work correctly. The problem is that another exception is thrown when i try to using the operator/ overload for concatenating different path, and i didn't find any workaround from this problem.

The strangest thing occurred when i discovered that the release build of the project worked correctly. I found online another answer that suggest the problem could be that i'm importing the wrong boost library, but i'm actually already using boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_64.lib in debug mode and boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_64.lib, so i don't think this is the case.

Any idea of what the problem could be?

EDIT I was asked with a minimal, complete example and i can provide a simple one, because it's the one i used to verify the problem existence. If i write a simple main like:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

std::string s1("C:/Programs");
std::string s2("Program.exe");

boost::filesystem::path path1(s1);
boost::filesystem::path path2(s2);

boost::filesystem::path definitivePath = path1 / path2;

std::cout << definitivePath;

return 0;
}
```

If i build this in debug mode and try to run it with a debugger active, the exception is thrown in the third line of main, when i try to build a path object. If i use

```
std::wstring s1(L"C:/Programs");
std::wstring s2(L"Program.exe");
```

instead the constructor work properly, but i always get an exception on the penultimate line, when i try to concatenate the two path (this happens also if i use \ instead of / in the name path).

If i run the application in a release build instead, without the debugger, it work correctly (i can say it because the cout print correctly the concatenated path).

Other useful info: i'm using the latest version of QT Creator as an IDE with the following line in the .pro file to include the libraries (built with VS2015 x64, the same one i use in QT Creator):

```
win32{
    INCLUDEPATH += E:/pathToBoost
    DEPENDPATH += E:/pathToBoost/stage/lib
    LIBS += -LE:/pathToBoost/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_64
    CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
        # debug
        LIBS += -LE:/pathToBoost/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_64
    } else {
        # release
        LIBS += -LE:/pathToBoost/stage/lib-release/lib -lboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_64
    }
```

Comment: [Off topic] `&*c.begin(), &*c.begin() + c.size()` can be written as `&c[0], &c[c.size()]`?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so we can try it out?

Comment: I edited the answer with some other info and a test code, check it out please!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. A side note: I've never manually added the boost-library to the linker (in QT or VS), only the library directory itself. Have you tried this yet ? There _might_ be something wrong.